# Good practice loading assets LibGDX HTML (GWT)

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx, assets

I'm creating a game that will mainly run on browser thanks to GWT HTML5 deployment. I have quite a few MB of assets between images and sounds. Obviously I don't need them all at all times. I'd like to load them depending on the screen that's coming next and other parameters. That is specially critical because my main deployment will be on web (can't load all 50MB when starting just in case they will be used).

I don't really know how asset loading works on LibGDX on HTML5 really. I'd like to use the AssetManager or something similar to load my TextureAtlases and Sounds but I think HTML5 deployment just loads everything in the beginning regardless if I later use the AssetManager in the core project.

What would be a correct asset loading pipeline with libGDX and GWT. It would be awesome to load all from the core project because that way would be multiplatform for the future but it is not critical now so the important part is to load assets wisely on the web.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommended way of managing assets:

```
// load texture atlas
final String spriteSheet = "images/spritesheet.pack";
assetManager.load(spriteSheet, TextureAtlas.class);
// blocks until all assets are loaded
assetManager.finishedLoading();
// all assets are loaded, we can now create our TextureAtlas object
TextureAtlas atlas = assetManager.get(spriteSheet);
// (optional) enable texture filtering for pixel smoothing
for (Texture t: atlas.getTextures())
    t.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

Now to load a sprite you do:

```
// Create AtlasRegion instance according the given <atlasRegionName>
final String atlasRegionName = "regionName";
AtlasRegion atlasRegion = atlas.findRegion(atlasRegionName);
// adjust your sprite position and dimensions here
final float xPos = 0;
final float yPos = 0;
final float w = asset.getWidth();
final float h = asset.getHeight();
// create sprite from given <atlasRegion>, with given dimensions <w> and <h>
// on the position of the given coordinates <xPos> and <yPos>
Sprite spr = new Sprite(atlasRegion, w, h, xPos, yPos);
```

Comment: This is more or less what I do but I have a pretty big project. I call a different load every new screen (that basically creates a texture atlas) with the images needed for each screen. So I have a Texture Pack for each screen. Looking at the server load GWT is loading them all in the beginning no matter what. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid that and make LibGDX make requests in runtime.